# Saturation of null ideal

Tags: set-theory

In ZFC, can we find more than continuum many non null sets of reals whose pairwise intersections are null?

Comment: You have it already as a consistency assertion?

Comment: Yes, e.g. under CH, there is a Sierpinski set so we can use an $\omega_2$ sized almost disjoint family on $\omega_1$ to construct such a family.

Comment: Yes, I just came to a similar conclusion myself...

Comment: Can't you do some sort of diagonalization on mutually disjoint Bernstein sets?

Comment: Asaf, i don't see how to do a "diagonalization" in just ZFC. I just found this on mad families in Solovay's model: http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.07577. Maybe you can take the inaccessible away.

Comment: I've been meaning to send you an email about this topic. But thanks for the reference. Let's meet next week and talk about it. I'll be on campus most week, so you just have to show up before 18:00 :-)

Comment: Sure. On sunday i attend bar-ilan talks but i will be at ross starting monday.

Comment: Great. We can meet on Monday.

Comment: I think this fails if continuum is real valued measurable. I will post details soon.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no. Observe that it is enough to show that, consistently, the density of the boolean algebra $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) / Null$ is continuum (which means that there are continuum many non null sets such that every non null set contains one of them). For this, it suffices to show that, consistently, ($\star$) holds:

($\star$): $2^{\omega} = \kappa = \kappa^{< \kappa}$ and every non null set of reals has a non null subset of size less than $\kappa$.

Claim 1: If $\kappa = 2^{\omega}$ is real valued measurable, then ($\star$) holds.

Proof: That $\kappa^{< \kappa} = \kappa$, is a result of Prikry (Theorem 22.2 in Jech's book). Let $\langle x_i : i < \kappa \rangle$ be a one-one enumeration of a non null set of reals $X$. Force with the null ideal of a measure on $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$. Let $j: V \to M$ be the generic elementary embedding with critical point $\kappa$. Note that, in $M$, $X$ is a non null initial segment of $j(X)$ - this is because forcing with a measure algebra preserves old non null sets; so this also holds in $V$.

Claim 2: ($\star$) holds in the random real model.

Proof: (Communicated by Arnold Miller) Let $V \models GCH$, and $P$ add $\omega_2$ random reals $\langle r_i : i < \omega_2 \rangle$. Suppose $X = \langle x_i : i < \omega_2 \rangle$ is non null. Define $X_i = V[\langle r_j : j < i \rangle] \cap X$. Choose $\alpha < \omega_2$ of cofinality $\omega_1$ such that no null set coded in $V[\langle r_j : j < \alpha \rangle]$ covers $X_{\alpha}$. So $X_{\alpha}$ is non null in $V[\langle r_j : j < \alpha \rangle]$ and it remains so in $V[\langle r_i : i < \omega_2 \rangle]$.